# How to display the posts belonging to a paticular category

Tags: categories

I have to display the posts belonging to a particular category in the home page.As I am new to word press I don't know how to do it.PLease help me

Comment: This question is fairly broad. What have you tried? How much of the [WordPress Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) do you understand?

Answer (score -1):

Use the following codes in the **page.php** file or in the home page template if you have created any. Use [Child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) to edit your theme files

```
if( is_home() || is_front_page() ) {
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page'   => -1, // To show all the posts
        'cat' => cat_id // Replace cat_id with the actual category id
    );

    // The Query
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    // The Loop
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
            $the_query->the_post();
            echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
        }
    } else {
    // no posts found
    }
    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

For more detail, see the [function Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters)

Comment: The `home.php` template file is reserved for the **blog posts index**, and should **not** be used as a custom *site front page* template. For that purpose, use `front-page.php`, or create a *custom page template*.